# Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Logic using Accord.NET?

Tags: neural-network, fuzzy-logic, accord.net

Is it possible to design a neuro fuzzy system using Accord.NET. I can't fins anything regarding neuro fuzzy systems in Accord documentation. Has anyone done this before, Is there any technique to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I look at this file: https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Fuzzy/InferenceSystem.cs

Accord.net seems to support fuzzy inference system (FIS). So now have to figure out how you want to model membership functions (MF) using parameters. Then use special neural network (NN) to model those rules such that as NN is trained MF parameters are tuned to give you best results.